# How do I load local file as JSON source? AIR & Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: json, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

In a very simple first AIR application (I'm using Flash Builder 4.5), I am trying to accomplish the following on my MacBook:

1. Read a local file (JSON format) into the AIR app.
2. Parse through the file.
3. Display some selected contents in a grid.

That's it.

I've found an example that does some simple JSON parsing in Flex, but the problem is that it loads the JSON source from a remote web site.

So do I need to load any file-specific libraries to make this work in AIR? Or can I simply refer to the file by using the Mac file-path? I just want the local file to be the JSON source. The parsing is already taken care of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FileStream like:

```
var myFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("AIR Test/test.txt");
var myFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
myFileStream.open(myFile, FileMode.READ);
var yourJSONdata:String = myFileStream.readUTFBytes(myFileStream.bytesAvailable);
myFileStream.close();
```

[Initializing a FileStream object, and opening and closing files](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Filesystem_11.html)

Comment: Nemi, I really appreciate the feedback. Thank you!